# How to match except in cloud firestore rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So I want to give read rights to all entities except one collection.

I want to say "document that doesn't match userPrivate"

How do I do that?

I want to make sure this generally catching match {document=**} doesn't allow reading of userPrivate

[image]

Comment: I don't think that having a rule that grants access to everything *except* on document or collection is a good idea.  Consider restructuring your data to make it easier to express your security rules.  Perhaps there could be just one collection with subcollections that are accessible to everyone, and you could write a single rule to protect that one collection.

Comment: ah yeah. that was my "next next refactor" haha. was hoping I could get by until then somehow

Answer (score -1):

You should match userPrivate and in it place

```
allow read, write: if false;
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work, because the 'permit' rules take precedence over the 'deny' ones. So the allow in the match for /{document=**} will override your answer, wherever that is placed.